# call method on an arbitrary attribute in user-defined class

Tags: python, class, object, methods

Ok, this is probably really simple but I'm struggling. So, let's say I have a simple class "Simple" that has some attributes a and b. And I have a method, "trim" that can be used on one attribute at a time:

```
class Simple():

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def trim(self.[???]):
        ...do some stuff...
        return self
```

Now, I want the user to be able to apply the method to any of the attributes (i.e., a and b) with something like:

```
simple_with_a_trimmed = simple.trim('a')
```

or

```
simple_with_b_trimmed = simple.trim('b')
```

How can I set up the method so that I can pass it the appropriate attribute? Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) methods. These allow you to refer to a class attribute by a string.

You can pass the desired attribute to the `trim` method. You can then retrieve the value of the specified attribute using `getattr`. Then, you can either transform it, and return it, or perhaps modify it using `setattr` -- to *update* the object.

Below is a simple example of this in action. The `trim1` method merely returns the value of the (transformed) attribute but does not update the object. The `trim2` method *changes* the object itself -- it updates the value of the specified attribute.

I've also added a `__str__` method to show how the object changes after each call.

```
class Simple:

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def trim1(self, attr):
        # Get value of the attribute
        current_value = getattr(self, attr)

        # Transform and return the value of the attribute
        # Removing whitespace as an example
        return current_value.strip()

    def trim2(self, attr):
        # Get value of the attribute
        current_value = getattr(self, attr)

        # Transform the value of the attribute
        # Removing whitespace as an example
        current_value = current_value.strip()

        # Update the value of the attribute
        setattr(self, attr, current_value)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'a: "{self.a}", b: "{self.b}"'

# Create an object of type Simple
simple = Simple('  data1', 'data2   ')

# These methods do not change the object, but return the transformed value
a = simple.trim1('a')
b = simple.trim1('b')
print(f'Returned value of a: "{a}"')
print(f'Returned value of b: "{b}"')

print(simple)  # Prints `a: "  data1", b: "data2   "`

# Apply the transformation to attribute `a`
simple.trim2('a')

print(simple)  # Prints `a: "data1", b: "data2   "`

# Apply the transformation to attribute `b`
simple.trim2('b')

print(simple)  # Prints `a: "data1", b: "data2"`
```